# How do I fix a Pytorch install error on a windows virtual environment with an error that says Pytorch could not be found from a pip command?

Tags: python, pytorch, python-venv

Thank you for taking the time to look at this thread.  I am running windows 11 and created a virtual environment that was setup with Python 3.10.2.  I installed jupyter notebook, tensorflow, CUDA 11.6 toolkit, and cuDNN 8.3.2.  I went to the PyTorch website and clicked the long term stable version of PyTorch for windows using Pip on the CUDA 11.1 option.

This produced the following Pip command:

```
pip3 install torch==1.8.2+cu111 torchvision==0.9.2+cu111 torchaudio===0.8.2 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/lts/1.8/torch_lts.html
```

I ran this command inside of my terminal as well as the jupyter notebook whose kernel was connected to my virtual environment and received the following error:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch==1.8.2+cu111 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for torch==1.8.2+cu111
```

Does anybody have any advice that could help me solve this issue?
I am running a machine with a GTX 2060 and an AMD Ryzen processor.  To my knowledge, I should be able to run CUDA with my GPU.  I attempted to troubleshoot the issue by using the stable version of PyTorch as well but still received the same error.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

OK, well now I feel silly.  I went back to the PyTorch website and saw that PyTorch only works up to Python 3.9 as of today in case anyone else runs into a similar issue.